# Spyder hangs while running script, persists after re-installation

Tags: linux, python, anaconda

When I run a python script (that worked perfectly just a few days ago) Spyder (through Anaconda) just hangs and doesn't put out any info. It'll output 'runfile(blah/blah)' but it'll just stay there. No errors or issues.

I haven't changed the script or any software but I did have to restart my laptop because I forgot to charge it.

I've since tried to re-install Anaconda, change where Anaconda is install (default is root), upgrading and downgrading, all with no luck.

Anaconda2, Spyder 3.3.2 running Python 2.7, RHEL 7

Comment: Can you add the details of the script, i.e. what may make it hang? a file not being there anymore, some internet site being down, etc. could all be potential reasons

Comment: @user2813274 I can't really (work stuff). But it shouldn't be anything in the script because the script hasn't changed since the last time it ran successfully. That's why it's so confusing. I can make a file that is literally just 'print('hi')' and it still hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling "user module reloading" under python interpeter in preferences. It seems to hang on that for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).